# Is it possible to concatenate a string and expression without converting the expression into string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, concatenation, sympy

In my quest to learn Python for mathematics course, I have stumbled upon a rather unique problem. I'm looking to concatenate the output of an integration (an equation) along with a string say "Fx(x)" and using the print command to concatenate them results in the integration output been converted into string.

Link for the image to describe the issue - [Desired Concatenation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5R6wV.png)

The output of the integration is 1/x+1 and I would like it to be displayed normally as it would be in a textbook and not in the string format.

Following is my code

```
from sympy import integrate, symbols, exp, oo
from IPython.display import display, Markdown

x, y = symbols('x,y', positive=True)

integral = integrate(exp(-y*(x+1)), (y, 0, oo))

display(Markdown(r'$f_X(x) =$')) 

integral
```

The current output of this code shows both in different lines, while the output I'm looking for it Fx(X) = 1/x+1, as it would be displayed in a textbook.

Answer (score 0):

```
print("Fx(X)=", integral)

o/p
Fx(X) = 1/(x + 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But this is normal concatenation and like I have mentioned it results in the expression been converted into string. The output I'm looking for is how it would be displayed in a normal textbook preserving its equation form.

I can't post an image to explain it, but if you run my code as it is and see how the output of "integral" is then you would get what I'm trying to convey.

Comment: Ok I could upload the image and here is the link to same. https://i.stack.imgur.com/5R6wV.png . You can see the output of print command changes the expression into string, while the actual output of integration is visually different.

Comment: @david.anto7  integral = "Fx(X) =" + str(integral) , print(integral)

Comment: The problem with print command is that it converts the output into a string. If you look at the image link, you can see the difference between the print command output and the output of integrate function. I don't if it is possible in Python, but the desired output is a concatenate of Fx(X) string with the output of integration.